# Loading clients views before default views if exists

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In my project (BtoB project), I have a global application with a lot of modules in it.
Each module provides common functionnalities, for all of my clients.

I have also in the root directory a clients folder, in it, I have all clients specificities, in their folder.
Thoses folders, aren't modules. So they are not loaded with Zf2. I usually load those specificities with abstractFactories.

This architecture follow is what I have currently :

```
-   clients
    -   clientOne
        -   Invoice
        -   Cart
        -   Orders

    -   clientTwo
        -   Invoice
        -   Orders

    -   clientThree
        -   Reporting

-   module
    -   Application
    -   CartModule
    -   InvoiceModule
    -   OrdersModule
    -   Reporting
```

My clients wants to have some custom views, sometimes, they ask us to provide those views. But my application give a common view for all of them. I have to modify this architecture to load a client view if it exist, or load the common view.

To handle this case I Imagine to have into each clients folder this :

```
-   client
    -   clientOne
        -   Invoice
        -   Cart
            -   View
                - cartView.phtml
        -   Orders
```

**EDIT :**

After some good answers (@AlexP & @Wilt), I tried to implements this solution :

So I have a ClientStrategy; it's factory is Like This :

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Strategy;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

use Application\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver;
use Zend\View\Resolver;

class ClientStrategyFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $viewRenderer = $serviceLocator->get('ViewRenderer');
        $session = new \Zend\Session\Container('Session');

        $map = $serviceLocator->get('config')['view_manager']['template_map'];
        $resolver = new Resolver\AggregateResolver();
        $map = new TemplateMapResolver($map, $this->clientMap($session->offsetGet('cod_entprim')));

        $resolver
            ->attach($map)
            ->attach(new Resolver\RelativeFallbackResolver($map));

        $viewRenderer->setResolver($resolver);

        return new ClientStrategy($viewRenderer);
    }


    /**
     * permet de retourner le namespace du client selectionné avec la relation codpriml / nom de dossier
     * @return array
     */
    public function clientMap($codprim)
    {
        $clients = array(
            21500 => 'clientOne',
            32000 => 'clientTwo',
            // ..
        );

        return (isset($clients[$codprim])) ? $clients[$codprim]: false;
    }
}
```

My clientMap method allow me to load my client folder, and views it may have in it like this :

```
class ClientOne
{
    /**
     * get The main Code
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCodEntPrim()
    {
        return 21500;
    }

    /**
     * Load all customs views
     * @return array
     */
    public function customViews()
    {
        return array(
            'addDotations' => __DIR__ . '/Dotations/view/dotations/dotations/add-dotations.phtml',
        );
    }

    /**
     * GetName 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return get_class();
    }
}
```

So when it comes to my TemplateMapResolver to do his job I do this :

```
<?php
namespace Application\View\Resolver;

class TemplateMapResolver extends \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver
{
    /**
     * Client name to use when retrieving view.
     *
     * @param  string $clientName
     */
    protected $clientName;

    /**
     * Merge nos vues avec celle clients avant de repeupler l'arrayMap global
     * @param array $map [description]
     */
    public function __construct(array $map, $client)
    {
        $this->setClientName($client);
        if ($this->getCLientName()) {
            $map = $this->mergeMap($map);
        }
        parent::__construct($map);
    }

    /**
     * Merge les map normales avec les map clients, pas propre ?
     * @param  array $map
     * @return array
     */
    public function mergeMap($map)
    {
        $name = $this->getClientName() . '\\' . $this->getClientName() ;
        $class = new $name;
        $clientMap = $class->customViews();
        return array_replace_recursive($map, $clientMap);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a template path by name
     *
     * @param  string $name
     * @return false|string
     * @throws Exception\DomainException if no entry exists
     */
    public function get($name)
    {
        return parent::get($name);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the Client name to use when retrieving view.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getClientName()
    {
        return $this->clientName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the Client name to use when retrieving view.
     *
     * @param mixed $clientName the client name
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setClientName($clientName)
    {
        $this->clientName = $clientName;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of things, this works but somes issues cames up :

> - My template_path_stack not works anymore, so a lot of my views are broken.
> - I think this is a complete mess, to do this, that way.
> - Hard to maintain.
> - I understand a bit better, how it works, but i'm still unable to implements it the good way.

Comment: Look at Zend\View template_path_stack.  However you may want to be explicit with your view/template mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just saw that I may want to use Resolver than ViewStrategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I solved my problem, but i'm not sure it's the good way to do it. So if someone can do better, I let the bounty runs for a better solution, if exists.

Here is what I've done :

```
/**
 * Factory permettant d'établir que les vues client soient chargé si elle existent, avant les vues par défaut.
 */
class ClientStrategyFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $viewRenderer = $serviceLocator->get('ViewRenderer');
        $session = new \Zend\Session\Container('Session');
        $clientList = $serviceLocator->get('Config')['customers_list'];
        $clientName = $this->clientMap($session->offsetGet('cod_entprim'), $clientList);
        $clientMap = new TemplateMapResolver($clientName);
        $viewRenderer->resolver()->getIterator()->insert($clientMap, 2);

        return new ClientStrategy($viewRenderer);
    }


    /**
     * permet de retourner le namespace du client selectionné avec la relation codpriml / nom de dossier
     * @param integer $codprim
     * @param array $clientList
     * @return array
     */
    public function clientMap($codprim, $clientList)
    {
        return (isset($clientList[$codprim])) ? $clientList[$codprim]: false;
    }
}
```

You can see that my custom TemplateMapResolver needs a clientName, this is for loading custom views. But the most important thing is : I don't create a new Resolver, I just add my Resolver to the list by this line :

```
$viewRenderer->resolver()->getIterator()->insert($clientMap, 2);
```

The second argument means, that this resolver is top priority (Default priority is 1)

My TemplateMapResolver is pretty much simple, the most important thing is this :

```
 public function __construct($client)
    {
        $this->setClientName($client);
        if ($this->getCLientName()) {
            $map = $this->getMap();
        } else {
            $map = array();
        }
        parent::__construct($map);
    }

    /**
     * Return all custom views for one client
     * @param  array $map
     * @return array
     */
    public function getMap()
    {
        $name = $this->getClientName() . '\\' . $this->getClientName() ;
        $class = new $name;
        return $class->customViews();
    }
```

My solution, force me to create then a class in my clients folder with the same name of the folder so, if my clientName is TrumanShow i will have an architecture like :

```
- [clients]
-- [TrumanShow]
--- TrumanShow.php
--- [Cart]
---- [view]
----- [cart]
------ [index]
------- cart-view.phtml
--- [Invoice]
--- [Reporting]
```

And in this file I will have this function that declare all my custom views :

```
/**
     * Ici nous mettons nos custom views afin de les charger dans le template Map
     * @return array
     */
    public function customViews()
    {
        return array(
            'cartView' => __DIR__ . '/Cart/view/cart/index/cart-view.phtml',
        );
    }
```

So it's possible to do this without break `template_path_stack` or my others routes. Now I have to call `setTemplate` method in my Controller, like this :

```
// code ...

public function cartAction() {
    $view->setTemplate('cartView');

    return $view;
}
```

And ZendFramework will check first if a custom view exists in my clients folder, or load the common view if no view is found.

Thanks to @Wilt and @AlexP for their contribution and help.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do that (I am not so sure if it is the best way) then you can extend the `TemplateMapResolver` with your custom logic and set it in your `Renderer` instance.

Make your custom class:

```
<?php
Application\View\Resolver

class TemplateMapResolver extends \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver
{
    /**
     * Client name to use when retrieving template.
     *
     * @param  string $clientName
     */
    protected $clientName; 

    /**
     * Retrieve a template path by name
     *
     * @param  string $name
     * @return false|string
     * @throws Exception\DomainException if no entry exists
     */
    public function get($name)
    {
        if ($this->has($clientName . '_' . $name)) {
            return $this->map[$clientName . '_' . $name];
        }
        if (!$this->has($name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $this->map[$name];
    }
}
```

And now something like:

```
$resolver = new TemplateMapResolver();
$resolver->setClientName($clientName);

// Get the renderer instance 
$renderer->setResolver($resolver);
```

You might still have to take care of setting the map in the resolver. Maybe you can just get it from the old resolver? I am not sure... That is for you to find out. This is just to get you on the correct way.

So if you set `cart_view` as a template it will first try to get `client_name_cart_view` if not found it sets `cart_view`.

### UPDATE

If you want to take this to the next level, then what you can do is make a custom view model for example `ClientViewModel` that extends the normal `ViewModel` class.
The constructor for this `ClientViewModel` takes both a client and a template name:

```
new ClientViewModel($client, $template, $variables, $options);
```

`$variables` and `$options` are optional and can be passed to the `parent::__construct` (constructor of the normal `ViewModel`)

The next step would be to create a `Application\View\ClientStrategy`.

This strategy is connected on render event and in this strategy you add a `ViewRenderer` instance with your custom `TemplateMapResolver` set. During rendering you can get your client from your `ViewModel` and find the correct template in your `TemplateMapResolver` using this client.

More details can be found online, there are examples. Check for example [here](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/zend-framework-2-step-by-step-create-custom-view-strategy/).

The advantage will be that other views with `ViewModel` or `JsonModel` will be rendered as normally, only your `ClientViewModel` gets a special treatment. Thus you are not breaking your applications default logic.

Comment: Thanks wilt, there is some things really nice in your post. I don't know how to load client views from your answer. Like you said maybe it's up to me to find out. In controller I always let my PHPrendererStrategy find my view so i never set a template explicitely, is that a problem for you solution ?

Comment: @Hooli maybe you have to dynamically build your template map with a file reader, set the template names accordingly (client_name + view_name) and then set the map to the Resolver...

Comment: I have to do the simple case, first and add more when it works i'll give a shot to your idea. And i come back here.

Comment: Silly question, this resolver not called at all, wich configuration i missed to allow this resolver to be called ? (get method i mean)

Comment: Where do you set it? You should check whether it is actually your Resolver being used... You most likely have to inject it somewhere else then in a controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97951/discussion-between-hooli-and-wilt).

Comment: Take this to the next level is in fact what I supposed I have to do in the first place with a new View Strategy. I will take the time to make this and give you feed back about this.

Comment: You told me that you was interested by a solution, I post an answer with mine.

Comment: Even if I solved My problem by myself, our discussion in chat and your answer worth 50 rep. Thank you for your help, anyway don't hesitate to give your feedback about my answer, your advices are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Requirements

- Multiple possible views per client
- Default view fallback if client specific view not found

Create a new service, say `TemplateProviderService` which has a simple interface.

```
interface ViewTemplateProviderInterface
{
    public function hasTemplate($name);
    public function getTemplates();
    public function setTemplates($templates);
    public function getTemplate($name);
    public function setTemplate($name, $template);
    public function removeTemplate($name);
    public function removeTemplates();

}
```

Inject and hard code the template name in controller classes.

```
// Some controller class
public function fooAction()
{
   $view = new ViewModel();
   $view->setTemplate($this->templateProvider->get('some_view_name'));

   return $view;
}
```

Now you can create client specific factories that inject custom template script config into your template provider. All you would then need to do is decide which template provider service you want to inject into your controller.

```
class ViewTemplateProviderFactory
{
    public function __invoke($sm, $name, $rname)
    {
        $config = $sm->get('config');

        if (! isset($config['view_template_providers'][$rname])) {
            throw new ServiceNotCreatedException(sprintf('No view template provider config for \'%s\'.', $rname));
        }

        return new ViewTemplateProvider($config['view_template_providers'][$rname]);
    }
}
```

The key here is ALL view scripts, for all clients, are registered under the 'view_manager' key as normal however the name of the template in the *controller* never changes.

**Edit**

You could just use one factory and pull from config (see changes above).

```
return [
    'view_template_providers' => [
        'ClientOneTemplateProvider' => [
            'some_view_name' => 'name_of_script_1'
        ],
        'ClientTwoTemplateProvider' => [
            'some_view_name' => 'name_of_script_2'
        ],
        'ClientThreeTemplateProvider' => [
            'some_view_name' => 'name_of_script_3',
        ],
    ],
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            'ClientOneTemplateProvider'   => 'ViewTemplateProviderFactory',
            'ClientTwoTemplateProvider'   => 'ViewTemplateProviderFactory',
            'ClientThreeTemplateProvider' => 'ViewTemplateProviderFactory',
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_map' => [
            'name_of_script_1' => __DIR__ . 'file/path/to/script',
            'name_of_script_2' => __DIR__ . 'file/path/to/script',
            'name_of_script_3' => __DIR__ . 'file/path/to/script',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it's a nice way to do it, The fact is : my client folder is not a module, juste a folder psr4 autoloaded in composer. Do you think each teamplateProviderFactory can be loaded from My Application module ? How can i do it ?

Comment: @Hooli You only need one factory really; you could load the configuration from the service manager using the `$rname` argument. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Autoloading is autoloading; providing the class can be found (and has an `__invoke` method) is should work.

Comment: The idea behind my Client folders is, when we lost a client we just deactivate the autoloader, and all config, code, about him is deactivate, even config, there is no debt. You see ?

Comment: I'm not sure on you project specifics, however I would go for a module per client; with all config specific to a client within that module. Then removing a client would be simply removing there module from the `application.config.php` and `composer.json`.

Comment: Yeah I had this idea once, the main problem with it is : A cleint is not a module. I can't load 500 modules one for each client I have, there is no need of that (it will be a mess for performance...). I just need to have or not a client folder with specificities or not, depends on them.

Answer (score -1):

Don't overcomplicate things.  Just set the ViewModel's template before you render it.

```
$vm = new ViewModel();
$vm->setTemplate( $user_service->getTemplate( $this->getRequest() ) );
return $vm;
```

Pretty clean if you inject your user into this fictitious user service, and use it to ascertain which template to inject.

The concern of the $user_service should be completely disparate from the concern for your Controller action.

Comment: sorry, this is what it is, i can't have user service if i have 70 clients. I need to do this Properly

Comment: Down vote it all you want, it's the right way to do it.  Whether you have 5 clients or 500.  The logic that determines the client's template kit, should be encapsulated to maintain testable behavior.

Comment: I think using a new ViewStrategy with a Resolver make this possible. Because it's the aim of this layer. Sometimes Things are overcomplicated.